# I want to remove all elements between two selected elements in linked list java

Tags: java, linked-list, removeall

I want to remove all elements between two selected elements in linked list java I've tried with this code but it doesn't work .. Any suggestions !?

```
public <t> static void removeAtRange( int element1 ,
            int element2 ) {

    while ( i >= element1 && i < element2 && i < length.size()) {
        if (length.get(i)== element1) {
            Length.remove(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. What is length? What is Length? Where do you declare i? <t> should come after static, not before it.

Comment: Also you are only deleting the element if length(i) is the same as index of the element 1, that makes no sense.

Comment: I have list [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] I want to remove elements between 2 and 9 for example it will become [ 1,2,9,0]

Comment: What should happen if an element repeats?

Answer (score 0):

May be would be better to create new LinkedList, and place in it the first and last element from old list. If this solution is not perfect for you, replace cycle with iterator over collection. Then you can remove elements with this command:

```
iterator.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish something like this? Currently you are only removing the element at index `element1`.

```
public static void removeRange(List<?> list, int start, int end)
{
    if (end > list.size() || start < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    for (int x = start; x < end; x++) {
        list.remove(x);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I have list [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] I want to remove elements between 2 and 9 for example it will become [ 1,2,9,0]

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all elements between the given indices

```
public static void removeAtRange( int indexFrom , int indexTo ) {

    // TODO: Might be good to check these are valid indices in the linked list

    ArrayList toRemove = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = indexFrom+1; i< indexTo; i++){
        toRemove.add(ll.get(i));
    }

    ll.removeAll(toRemove); // remove all these from linkedlist

    System.out.println("After removing from =["+ indexFrom +"] to = ["+ indexTo +"] ll is =["+ ll.toString() +"]");

}
```